# How to merge the properties of all objects in a union type?

Tags: typescript

I have a schema defined

```
type Schema = {
    a: { a: 1 }
    b: { b: 2 }
}
```

And I want a function to create objects that conform to multiple schemas.

```
function createObject<K extends keyof Schema>(schema: Array<K>, obj: Schema[K]) {}

createObject(["a"], { a: 1 }) // works
createObject(["b"], { b: 2 }) // works
createObject(["a", "b"], { b: 2 }) // doesn't error but it should
createObject(["a", "b"], { a: 1, b: 2 }) // works
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Atype%20Schema%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20%7B%20a%3A%201%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20%7B%20b%3A%202%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createObject%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20Schema%3E(schema%3A%20Array%3CK%3E%2C%20obj%3A%20Schema%5BK%5D)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AcreateObject(%5B%22a%22%5D%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%201%20%7D)%0D%0AcreateObject(%5B%22b%22%5D%2C%20%7B%20b%3A%202%20%7D)%0D%0AcreateObject(%5B%22a%22%2C%20%22b%22%5D%2C%20%7B%20b%3A%202%20%7D)%20%2F%2F%20doesnt%20error%0D%0AcreateObject(%5B%22a%22%2C%20%22b%22%5D%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%202%20%7D)%20%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createObject2%3CK%20extends%20Array%3Ckeyof%20Schema%3E%3E(schema%3A%20K%2C%20obj%3A%20Schema%5BK%5Bnumber%5D%5D)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AcreateObject2(%5B%22a%22%5D%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%201%20%7D)%0D%0AcreateObject2(%5B%22b%22%5D%2C%20%7B%20b%3A%202%20%7D)%0D%0AcreateObject2(%5B%22a%22%2C%20%22b%22%5D%2C%20%7B%20b%3A%202%20%7D)%20%2F%2F%20doesnt%20error%0D%0AcreateObject2(%5B%22a%22%2C%20%22b%22%5D%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%202%20%7D)%20%2F%2F%20what%20I%20want.%0D%0A)

I've tried a few other things. Interestingly when you `&` a union with itself, it does a distributes the `&` across all items in the union and doesn't quite get me what I want. I want some to operate on `{a: 1} | {b: 2}` to get `{a: 1, b: 2}`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming the types inside your `Schema` properties are not themselves unions, you can [convert the union type `Schema[K]` to an intersection using conditional types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/2887218), like this:

```
type Schema = {
    a: { a: 1 }
    b: { b: 2 }
};    

type UnionToIntersection<U> =
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends
    ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

function createObject<K extends keyof Schema>(
    schema: Array<K>, 
    obj: UnionToIntersection<Schema[K]>
) { }

createObject(["a"], { a: 1 }) // works
createObject(["b"], { b: 2 }) // works
createObject(["a", "b"], { b: 2 }) // error! 
createObject(["a", "b"], { a: 1, b: 2 }) // works
```

This might be enough for you.  If you have some other use case (e.g., if `Schema` has a property like `cd: {c: 3} | {d: 4}` and you want there to still be a union in the final type) a different solution could be more appropriate:

```
type PropsToIntersection<T, K extends keyof T> =
    { [P in K]: (k: T[P]) => void }[K] extends
    ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;

function createObject<K extends keyof Schema>(
    schema: Array<K>,
    obj: PropsToIntersection<Schema, K>
) { }
```

That's similar except it walks through the keys of `Schema` and then performs an intersection, instead of spreading the union of `Schema[K]`.  Again, the difference only shows up in cases where some of your schema properties may themselves be unions.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Interesting! Can you explain how `infer` works in this context? I've never actually found a use for it before.

Comment: [Inference in conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#type-inference-in-conditional-types) with `infer` lets you pull a type out of a type expression.  So `ReturnType(()=>string)` evaluates to `string` because `(() => string)` matches `((...args: any[]) => infer R)` when `string` is inferred for `R`.

Comment: If you have multiple possible candidates for an inferred type, the compiler can return either a union or an intersection depending on how those candidates are used.   `((() => A) | (() => B)) extends (() => infer T) ? T : never` will produce `A | B` because function types are covariant in their return type.  But `((x: A) => void) | ((y: B) => void) extends ((z: infer T) => void) ? T : never` will produce `A & B` because function types are [contravariant in their argument types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#strict-function-types).

Comment: It is this inference of intersections when the inference sites are used in  contravariant positions that powers `UnionToIntersection` and `PropsToIntersection`.  We just take the types we'd like to intersect, put them in a contravariant position (e.g., function parameter), and do the inference to pull out the intersected type.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for this explanation. This all makes so much more sense now!